# ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint in SQL request

Tags: spring-boot

I have a constrain in database for unique email column value. I get into logs error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_7felfliwfxsdp14appb56m2c5"
  Detail: Key (email)=(strijdvjjng) already exists.
```

As a response from POST request I get:

```
"timestamp": "2023-12-27T16:05:36.052+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
```

Do you know how I can return properly from Spring Boot endpoint error message:

```
"timestamp": "2023-12-27T16:05:36.052+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Email already exists.",
```

or

```
{
   "Email already exists."
}
```

Do I need to implement a custom handler or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to create a custom exception and exception handler:

Example:

```
public class EmailException extends RuntimeException {
    public EmailException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}


public class ErrorResponse {
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private int status;
    private String error;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

you can create `controller advice` or simply add an `exception handler` to your controller class, it's up to you:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(EmailException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleEmailExistsException(EmailException ex) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(LocalDateTime.now(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
   
}
```

in your service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    public void createUser(User user) {
        try {
            
        } catch (ConstraintException e) {
             throw new EmailException("Email already exists.");              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, one question is not clear. What of I have 3 columns configured as unique constrain. How I can send custom message for each type of column exception?

Comment: Say you have `ConstraintViolationException` thrown by Spring, this exception doesn't directly tell you which column caused the issue. However, you can parse the exception message to figure out which constraint was violated and provide your custom exception accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To check your business constraints such as 'email address must be unique' you should perform a query to determine if the email is unique as part of your business requirements checks. If the email address isn't unique throw a custom exception. You can then use a global exception handler or the like to customize the response and code.